# Arranging by Alphabetical Order

Tags: java, arraylist, alphabet

I'm new to Java and I'm trying to arrange an arrayList of terms in alphabetical order. (A term is defined as a char and an int) (e.g. `{Term('Z',4),Term('C',3),Term('Q',2) ...} )`

My code is as follows:

```
    public Term nextElement()
{
    Term max = terms.get(0);
    char maxtest = max.getElement();
    for (int i = 1; i < terms.size(); i++){
        Term tester = terms.get(i);
        char maxtest2 = tester.getElement();
        if (maxtest2 > maxtest) {
            tester = max;
        }
    }
    return max;
}
```

Why isn't this working? and how do I accomplish this?
My arrayList is called term filled with type Term

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem with this line of Code. Your class is not a Type of `Comparable` So, On which property or criteria `compareTo()` method will `compare` these two objects ???

```
   res = maxtest.compareTo(maxtest2); //Your maxtest object is not Comparable Type.
```

You must need to make your class `Term` Comparable type. and , Override the method `compareTo()` as per your need.

You have not mentioning the variable's or structure of your class `Term` . So,  I am assuming that your class have such kind of Structure .

```
public class Term implements Comparable<Term> {
    private Character alpha;
   private int number;
   //getter and setters +Constructors as you specified
   ....
    ....
     ...
      .....
//  Now Set a criteria to sort is the Alphanumeric.
    @Override
    public int compareTo(Term prm_obj) {
        if (prm_obj.getAlpha() > this.alpha) {
            return 1;
        } else if (prm_obj.getAlpha() < this.alpha) {
            return -1;

        } else {
            return 0;
        }

    }
```

Now Your Class become a `comparable` Type. So you may apply `Collections.sort(Collection obj)` which automatically `sort` your `ArrayList<Term>`.

Here I write a demo for this.

```
public static void main(String... args){

    List<Term> obj_listTerm = new ArrayList<>();
     //add all the data you given in question
    obj_listTerm .add(new Term('Z', 4)); 
    obj_listTerm .add(new Term('Q', 2));
    obj_listTerm .add(new Term('c', 3));

    // print without Sorting your Term ArrayList.
    System.out.println("This is the list unsorted: " + myTermList);
    // Sort Using Collections.sort() Method.

    Collections.sort(myTermList);

    // After applying sort() you may see your Sorted ArrayList.
    System.out.println("This is the list SORTED: " + myTermList);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Collection class and sort the list of term you have, you need only to make the class Term **comparable**

## Example:

```
public class Term implements Comparable<Term> {
    .....
    //  .....
    //  criteria to sort is the char
    @Override
    public int compareTo(Term o) {
        if (o.getLetter()> this.letter) {
            return 1;
        } else if (o.getLetter() < this.letter) {
            return -1;

        } else {
            return 0;
        }

    }
```

---

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // test
    List<Term> myTermList = new ArrayList<>();
    myTermList.add(new Term('Z', 4));
    myTermList.add(new Term('Q', 2));
    myTermList.add(new Term('c', 3));
    // check how the look like
    System.out.println("This is the list unsorted: " + myTermList);
    // now sort them
    Collections.sort(myTermList);
    // check how the look like
    System.out.println("This is the list SORTED: " + myTermList);
}
```

## Edit>

if you dont want to implement comparable then modify this:

```
res = maxtest.compareTo(maxtest2);
```

because this is not valid since maxtest and maxtest2 are primitives and not objects...

use instead

```
res = Character.compare(maxtest, maxtest2);
```

and then use the result to verify your logic and make decisions:

```
if (res >1) {
            System.out.println("bigger");

        }else if (res<1) {
            System.out.println("smaller");

        }else {
            System.out.println("same");

        }
```

Comment: To do this, do I have to make another class - or just import one?

Comment: you can do all in the same class

Comment: just add to the Term class the implements Comparable<Term>

Comment: What about modifying my method? It says char cannot be dereferenced.
or is there a way to do it with the Max() method?

Comment: It says that Term is not abstract and does not override abstract method compareTo(Term) in java.lang.Comparable